# Why do I get this exception when clicking on a cell of a datagridview in winform in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, exception, code-conversion

I have a code in vb.net which i want to use in C#. The code is:

```
Dim cell As DataGridViewImageCell = CType(tempGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex), DataGridViewImageCell)
```

I am trying to get corresponding C# code:

```
public void gridmouseclick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        DataGridViewCell cell;

        for (i = 0; i <= 1 - 1; i++)
        {
            cell = (DataGridViewCell)grid[i].Rows[e.X].Cells[e.Y];   
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                cell.Value = imglst.Images[1];
            }
            else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                cell.Value = imglst.Images[0];
            }
        }
    }
```

`imglst` is a `ImageList` so now I am getting an exception when I am clicking on the grid cell the exception is:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

I am assigning the `gridmouseclick` like this....

```
grid[i].CellMouseClick += new DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(this.gridmouseclick);
```

How do I get rid of this exception?

Comment: SO is not a free code conversion service

Comment: i want help thats it.. i am new to c#

Comment: i tried that before coming here but their facing some problems thats why i post it here

Comment: @mitchwheat if u know c# can u help me on this? i just edited the question

Comment: yes find the solution it shouldn't be `MouseEventArgs e` it should be `DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is in C#:

```
DataGridViewImageCell cell = (DataGridViewImageCell)tempGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
```

Key points:

1. `CType(SourceObject, TargetType)` cast is written as `(TargetType)SourceObject`.
2. Indexing `Object(index)` is written with square brackets `Object[index]`
3. `Dim ObjectName as Type` declaration is written as `Type ObjectName`

Comment: i solved this conversion part can help me on the exception part?

Comment: yes find the solution it shouldn't be `MouseEventArgs e` it should be `DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e`

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
DataGridViewImageCell cell = 
(DataGridViewImageCell)tempGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
```

Comment: i solved this conversion part can help me on the exception part?

Comment: yes find the solution it shouldn't be `MouseEventArgs e` it should be `DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e`

Answer (score 0):

pleas change the type:

```
DataGridViewImageCell cell =  (DataGridViewImageCell)tempGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
```

Comment: i am not getting `e.RowIndex` i am getting `e.X`

Comment: yes find the solution it shouldn't be `MouseEventArgs e` it should be `DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e`